# "2-dimensional boolean indexing" , the error of ax.quiver() function when use cartopy

Tags: python, cartopy

An error: 2-dimensional boolean indexing is not supported. It appears when I want to draw wind field. I use ax.quiver() function of cartopy.

Here is the code:

```
dpath=r'E:\Data\Wind\era5wind2019.nc'
d=xr.open_dataset(dpath)
uw=d['u']
vw=d['v']
u=uw.loc['2019-01-01',:,:]
v=vw.loc['2019-01-01',:,:]
lat=uw.latitude
lon=uw.longitude

fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111,projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(180))
proj=ccrs.PlateCarree()
Q = ax.quiver(
        lon, lat, u, v, transform=proj,
        regrid_shape=20, angles='uv',
        scale=12, scale_units='xy',
        units='width', width=0.002
    )
```

Comment: This is not your issue, but I got this same error when I had projection=ccrs.LambertConformal() in the plot command and transform=ccrs.PlateCarree() in the quiver command...  Just thought I would add this as a comment in case it is helpful for readers looking for this error, but with this different cause. Setting both to platecarree as you have resolved the error for me

Answer (score 1):

I was having similar issues with ERA5 data, and found that the error disappears if you replace u and v in your call to ax.quiver with u.values and v.values.

When I tried it with ERA5 wind files of my own, I get the following warning, which vanishes if ccrs.PlateCarree() is given to both projection and transform.

```
~/.conda/envs/work/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cartopy/vector_transform.py:140: UserWarning: Some vectors at source domain corners may not have been transformed correctly
#   u, v = target_proj.transform_vectors(src_crs, x, y, u, v)
```

Comment: The error also  appears in NCEP dataset. So it may not be depended to the dataset. I tried to replace v with v.values also,but the result seems not good. I guess whether i make wrong formations of variables i.e. u,v.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that some or all of the relevant data: `lon`, `lat`, `u`, `v` are not in single dimension and of the same length.

You can use `.ravel()` to convert them to use in `.quiver()`:

```
Q = ax.quiver(lon.ravel(), lat.ravel(), u.ravel(), v.ravel(), ... )
```

This should work if the results have the same length.

Answer (score 0):

I got similar issue with my data and found out this was due to the fill values present in my variables.

I had to replace them by masked values before using `ax.quiver`:

```
u_msk = numpy.ma.masked_where(u > 1e30, u)
v_msk = numpy.ma.masked_where(v > 1e30, v)
```